# asp.net mvc controller controll partialview show/not show

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Assume there is a `_Layout.cshtml`, and on the bottom (even under the script src's) there is a `Html.Partial` which calls a partial view called "_Remodal".

**Bottom _Layout.cshtml**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/scripts/show-validation-error.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/scripts/app.js")"></script>

@Html.Partial("_Remodal")
```

**_Remodal**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      window.showOeps('oeps');
  })
</script>
```

And, this partial view will open something like this:
[image]

Is there any way for me to say inside a controller: 'Show this partial on the _Layout.cshtml'?

**controller e.g**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignIn(string email, string password)
{
    try
    {
        var user = userRepository.AuthorizedUser(email, password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            return View("~/Views/Questions/_Questions.cshtml");
        }
        else
        {
            // show @Html.Partial("_Remodal") on _Layout.cshtml
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I already tried things by using ajax and returning javascript, but it didn't work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Include a `boolean` property in your view model (or in `ViewBag`) that determines if your want to display it (and use an `if` statement in the view)

Comment: okeoke, sounds easy, is this boolean simple to set like: else {return false} ? :o can I return more than one variable (like a boolean and a string message to show inside the remodal popup)?

Comment: ps. like returning a modal or?

Comment: You can ad what ever properties you want - `ViewBag.ShowMessage = true; ViewBag.Message = "...."` etc and in the view `@if(ViewBag.ShowMessage) { @Html.Partial("_Remodal") .....`

Comment: Do I set those inside the controller? (found some info already but is quid complex and you say it like it's really ease)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ViewBag to set a flag which tells you whether you want to show it or not. check that in your partial view and hide/show the dialog.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignIn(string email, string password)
{
     try
     {
        var user = userRepository.AuthorizedUser(email, password);
        if (user != null)
        {
             return View("~/Views/Questions/_Questions.cshtml");
        }
        else
        {
             ViewBag.ShouldShowDialog = "Show";                
             return View("NotAuthorizedView");
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
            //log ex and show an error view to user
     }
  }
```

And in the Partial view,

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var shouldShow = "@ViewBag.ShouldShowDialog";
     if(shouldShow === "Show")
     {
        window.showOeps('oeps');
     }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: woo BIG THANKS! was already searching like hours for some kind of a solution.. Seriously big thanks!